# Spresense SDKで、USB MSC (Mass Storage Class) 機能を使いたい

Tags: spresense, arduino, usb

Spresense開発環境には、ArduinoとSpresense SDKが2種類あります

ArduinoにはUSB MSC機能がサンプルとしてあり動作確認できました

Spresense SDK(VS code)に同機能はないのでしょうか

これが使えると使い勝手が大きく変わるので是非SDKで使いたいです

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spresense SDK 環境 で USB MSC 機能を使って SD カードをマウントする場合、

SD カードのコンフィグは有効にした状態で、menuconfig を起動します。

> $ cd spresense/sdk  
>   $ ./tools/config.py device/sdcard -m

SDK Configuration 画面で、System tools > USB Mass Storage Device Commands を有効にしてビルドしてください。

[image: SDK Configuration]

SD カードを挿入して、拡張ボード側に USB ケーブルが刺さっている状態で、NuttShell プロンプトから "msconn" コマンドを打つと、USB MSC 機能が使用できます。

> nsh> msconn
>   mcsonn_main: Creating block drivers
>   mcsonn_main: Configuring with NLUNS=1
>   mcsonn_main: handle=d038d50
>   mcsonn_main: Bind LUN=0 to /dev/mmcsd0
>   mcsonn_main: Connected

反対に切断する場合は、"msdis" コマンドを使います。

> nsh> msdis
>   msdis: Disconnected

Comment: SDKコンフィグで有効にできるのですね
ご教授頂いた方法で、SDカードをMac(PC)からマウントし読み書きできる様になりました
ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

ご教授情報を元に、Visual Studio Code(VS code) GUIからも確認と変更ができる事がわかりました

１．
VS codeでワークスペースを開いた状態で、左の方で、ワークスペースのファイルリストがある所で右クリック
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

２．
Spresense: SDKコンフィグ　を選択

３．
SDKコンフィグが開き、一番上の方にスクロールすると、検索蘭があるので USBMSC　を入力する
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

４．
少し下の方にスクロールすると　SYSTEM_USBMSC　の項目がありチェックボックスがあります
この例ではチェックボックスを有効にし USBMSC が使えるカーネルを作れる様にする
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

５．
これを有効にしカーネルのビルドを実行
アプリケーションのビルドを実行
ビルドと書き込みを実行すると ターミナル nsh で、 "msconn"コマンドでUSB MSCを有効にできる様になりました
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

-EOF-